# Construct a variable name using a string and another variable in the same df and then update its value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to update variables in a `df` selected using a constructed name with a string and another variable in the same data frame.

Say my `df` is:

```
 df
  y index
1 4     1
2 8     5
3 4     3
4 6     2
```

to which I add five variables m.1 through m.5:

```
> df
  y index m.1 m.2 m.3 m.4 m.5
1 4     1   0   0   0   0   0
2 8     5   0   0   0   0   0
3 4     3   0   0   0   0   0
4 6     2   0   0   0   0   0
```

using something like this:

```
createvars <- function(df, n) { mutate(df, "m.{n}" := 0) }
for(i in 1:max(df$index)) {df <- createvars(df, n=i)}
```

I want to update the variables m.1 through m.5 using something like this `m.{n} := index` based on conditions that look something like this `{n} == index`.

The result then should look like:

```
> df
  y index m.1 m.2 m.3 m.4 m.5
1 4     1   1   0   0   0   0
2 8     5   0   0   0   0   5
3 4     3   0   0   3   0   0
4 6     2   0   0   0   4   0
```

Note, in the actual sample/application:

1. the number of variables `m.` will depend on the sample and can be several hundred,
2. the values in the variables `m.` will be functions of `index` and other variables in the `df`,
3. the `df` will ultimately be used in `lm(y~)` and this might not be the right way to proceed.

Any suggestion how to accomplish this?

Thanks tons for any suggestion!!!!

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `tibble` solution could be:

```
df %>%
 add_column(!!!setNames(rep(0, 5), paste0("m", 1:5))) %>%
 mutate(across(starts_with("m"), ~ +(paste0("m", index) == cur_column()) * index))

  y index m1 m2 m3 m4 m5
1 4     1  1  0  0  0  0
2 8     5  0  0  0  0  5
3 4     3  0  0  3  0  0
4 6     2  0  2  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier with `row/column` indexing in `base R`

```
# // create the 'm.' columns with 0 values
nm1 <- paste0('m.', 1:5)
df[nm1] <- 0
# // assign the elements that corresponds to row/column index with index
df[nm1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$index)] <- df$index
```

-output

```
df
#  y index m.1 m.2 m.3 m.4 m.5
#1 4     1   1   0   0   0   0
#2 8     5   0   0   0   0   5
#3 4     3   0   0   3   0   0
#4 6     2   0   2   0   0   0
```

---

Or another option is `model.matrix` from `base R`

```
df[nm1] <- model.matrix(~ factor(df$index, levels = 1:5) - 1) * df$index
```

---

Or modify the function `createvars` and use a `for` loop

```
library(stringr)
createvars <- function(data, n) {
    data %>% 
      mutate(!! str_c('m.', n) :=  case_when(index == n ~ index, TRUE ~ 0L ))
 }
for(i in seq_len(max(df$index))) df <- createvars(df, i)
```

---

Or another option with `rowwise` and `unnest`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
mx <- max(df$index)
df %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(new = list(replace(numeric(mx), index, index))) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   unnest_wider(c(new)) %>% 
   rename_at(vars(starts_with("..")), ~ str_c('m.', seq_along(.)))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(y = c(4L, 8L, 4L, 6L), index = c(1L, 5L, 3L, 2L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data in wide format after creating a dummy column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), 
         col = paste0('m', index), 
         index1 = index) %>%
  complete(col = paste0('m', 1:max(index))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = index1, values_fill = 0) %>%
  filter(!is.na(row)) %>%
  arrange(row) %>%
  select(-row)

#      y index    m1    m2    m3    m4    m5
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     4     1     1     0     0     0     0
#2     8     5     0     0     0     0     5
#3     4     3     0     0     3     0     0
#4     6     2     0     2     0     0     0
```